Flutter: Debugger not working, breakpoints disabled when application run in debug mode
A very strange behaviour I encountered while debugging one of my flutter project, in this very specific project I am not able to debug, if I add breakpoints in the project and start debugging the app, it will automatically disabled the breakpoints.

However, if I add breaking point in the main.dart file, it is working at that point :

But the breaking points are not working on any other file.
Things I have tried :

Flutter clean, Invalidate cache and restart
Update flutter version, earlier project was working with flutter 3.3.10, I updated it to work with flutter 3.22.2
Update flutter plugin used in android studio.

My other flutter projects works fine. Let me know if any other information is required from my side.
Any help would be much appreciated..
Thanks in advance

Have you ever tried to downgrade the Flutter or Dart plugins in Android Studio?

I'm using Flutter plugin in 77.1.3 and Dart in 232.10313.

@Rico : I was using Flutter plugin 80.0.2, which i upgraded to 81.0.2, didn't work.. Other projects work fine.

Check the imports, make sure all the imports have an absolute path. If your folders are named:

screens/components

make sure that your imports match exactly that name. If you write something like:
import 'package:myapp/Screens/components/file.dart'

it won’t work, it must be exactly
import 'package:myapp/screens/components/file.dart'


Thank you very much.. I was really stuck on this one for a very long time.. :)
